# iOS: Watch Kit paired device unavailable for development

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-watch

I can't run my Apple Watch application in XCode. My phone+watch is listed as a "Unavailable Device" and says "paired device unavailable for development". When I try to launch the app it says the same thing.

How can I resolve this?

I'm using XCode 7.1, iOS 9.0, WatchOS 2.0.1.

Comment: There was a similar question that was deleted, but it was still the top Google hit so I'm asking this again. I'm trying to update to iOS9.1 now and I'll see if that helps.

Answer (score 68):

This is what worked for me, and it is a lot easier and faster than un-pairing so I would try this first. From the Clock Face Swipe up, and click on the Ping iPhone button. After it makes a sound, go back in Xcode it should change no longer be unpaired or unavailable for development.

Comment: This worked for me. Plus I also quit and launched Xcode 7.3.1 and then it showed the paired Apple Watch was available for development.

Comment: This and a lot of messing around, quitting xcode and relaunching it. Just as I was about to try removing the derived data folder, it worked.

Comment: This worked for me ... I first repaired which removed the "unavailable for development" warning, but Xcode then complained "no paired device" ... pinging fixed everything, though made a loud sound even when iPhone was in silent mode :/ ... sorry Starbucks peeps lol

Comment: Worked for me as well (Xcode 10, iOS 12.0.1, watchOS 5). Thanks!

Comment: OMG didn't believe it was going to work. But it did! (Xcode 11, iOS 13.1, watchOS 6)

Comment: I am amazed this worked.  I didn't even need to restart Xcode, the watch immediately became available as soon as I pinged my phone.

Answer (score 41):

I had the same issue on iOS 9.1 + WatchOS 2.01 that XCode 7.1 kept saying "paired device not available for development". Here is what I did to solve it finally, not quite sure which step is critical -

1. Unpair my watch
2. Reboot both iPhone and apple watch
3. Pair them again, and setup my watch as a new one
4. Plug (unplug first) iPhone to Mac
5. On apple watch, say Trust the computer when it asks
6. Unplug and plug again

Bang! My apple watch is well recognized for development.
Hope it helps.

Comment: It has been a long journey, but finally worked following the steps.

Comment: Had the same problem; I think I tapped "Don't trust" by accident the first time. Setting up the watch as a "new" one presented the modal again, allowed me to trust my Mac, and therefore use the device for development.

Comment: this sounds like overkill :o(

Comment: I didn't have to do all this (pairing and repairing the watch in particular is a pretty time-intensive process). Closing and restarting Xcode was all I needed.

Comment: This is just driving me nuts !! Did every step from whole internet and Google servers around Milk Way. It just doesn't work !!!

Comment: I had to setup my watch as a new device. I'm on Xcode 9 with Watch OS 4. Power cycle both phone, and watch multiple times as well as the laptop.

Comment: Warning: Re-pairing will take a long time. 30mins to 1hr.

Comment: are u f**** kidding me? is there a way to improve this process Apple?

Comment: For me it was enough to just restart both devices (watch and phone)

Comment: Xcode 10.1, steps 1-5 sufficed. (yes, I'm sure they were overkill)

Answer (score 17):

I can confirm having this too by using the following configuration:
OS X, Xcode7.2 beta, iPhone5s with iOS9.2 and WatchOS 2.1

I unplugged the iphone again, closed and restarted Xcode and plugged in the iPhone again - than it worked fine!

Comment: Worked for me: Unplug iDevice-> Quit XCode-> Restart XCode -> Plug in iDevice

Comment: Worked for me in XCode 12.6.1: I connected iPhone to laptop, trusted the computer, but got the message that the Watch device was unavailable for development.  Unplugged the phone from laptop and plugged it back in, and it was available, but the build failed because I needed to select a development team: Select main project in Project Navigator, then, in the editor that appears, select each relevant target and set the development team.  Also needed to do it for the project itself under the All tab.  Then the app installed on the watch.

Answer (score 13):

Rebooting the Apple Watch worked for me, after that it displays the 'trust this computer' message which is required to debug the watch with XCODE.

Answer (score 13):

I just restart the Xcode to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

Deleting the 'famous' XCODE Derived Data folder did it for me.

Steps for newbies:

1. Close XCODE.
2. Delete the Derived Data folder, to find it's location go in XCODE to upper menu: XCODE -> Preferences -> Locations: Here click on the Derived Data arrow.
3. Reopen XCODE.

Tested on XCODE8.0.

Answer (score 6):

Go to Window--> Device and Simulator , Unpair device and Disconnect from cable and connect back works for me.

Answer (score 3):

It just happened to me and I fixed it by

1. quitting Xcode
2. putting the Watch on the charger
3. open Xcode
4. select the Watch App Target
5. select the iPhone paired to watch as the device to run
6. Wait until '(paired device unavailable for development)' or '(no paired Apple Watch)' disappears from device description at the Xcode
   toolbar
7. Run!

Answer (score 2):

I followed the steps above repeatedly and still got the same issue. What I found fixed the issue was not signing into iCloud and only using Messages instead. Once I did that it worked beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: What are the "steps above"? The answer of @Will? Consider make a comment to that answer.

Comment: Yes, @Will's answer helped. I would have but I do not have enough reputation points.

Comment: Disabled / turned off all iCloud settings, except keychain & Find my iPhone, and then xcode recognized the watch and was able to debug

Answer (score 2):

Deleting everything in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/watchOS DeviceSupport/` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with watchOS 2.1.
Unplugging my phone restarting Xcode and plugin in my phone did the trick. I suggest trying that before you re-pairing phone and watch

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with this too, using Xcode Beta 7.3 version 3. I updated to Xcode Beta 7.3 version 5 and it's working fine. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem as well.

What I do is quite simple, turn off bluetooth from iPhone and turn on, wait till apple watch got connected again.

Then fire up the app.

Answer (score 1):

I had to unlock the watch with my passcode.

- If already unlocked, lock it then unlock.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues with this too with Xcode 10.1 and Watch OS 5.x
Really need delete Xcode Derived data files, and reboot Watch, and click 'Trust' button in Watch for debug.

Answer (score 1):

my problem was having to authorize the computer from the Apple Watch... 
(with last release Xcode 10.2)

Answer (score 1):

For me the only thing that worked was unpairing the watch from the iPhone and setting it up as a new watch (restore from backp didn't work).

I tried unpairing in Xcode, deleting derived/cached data, platform support, restarting Xcode, all combinations of unplugging and restarting!  Nothing worked.

Whether it was this nuclear action, or the simple fact that it then goes through the re-authorisation process between the Mac + Watch, we'll never know.

What I do know is that at times Xcode can be shockingly unstable.

Comment: Worked for me as well. The important step was to set up the watch as a new one, instead of restoring it from backup.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me over the last few days.  Xcode was being extremely unstable (sometimes, in the Build Scheme, it would say "paired watch unavailable for development", other times it would say "null" when referring to the watch, other times it would work!).  I did all of the steps below, but the inconsistency was not solved:

Unpair my watch, Reboot both iPhone and apple watch, Pair them again, and setup my watch as a new one, Plug (unplug first) iPhone to Mac, On apple watch, say Trust the computer when it asks, Unplug and plug again

Eventually, the I realised a slightly newer version of Mojave (10.14.5), and a slightly newer version of iOS (12.3.1) had been released.  After I made these quick updates, XCode appears to be much more stable now.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to `Trust this Mac` from my Watch.

Then I cleared the derived data, restarted XCode and it worked.
Didn't have to restart phone or Watch.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my phone to iOS9.1 and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I disable the passcode of apple watch, then DerivedData and restart Xcode solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the message after re-pairing which took about 30+ mins.

However, it could have been that restarting the watch would have fixed it so try that.

Also try deleting the `DerviedData`.

After I got the message to go away, the app wouldn't install on the phone. I had previously created a WatchKit project from an AppCode template. After creating a new project from XCode, it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Today I had the same issue. My phone was availbale for development but the watch was unavailable.
I restarted the iphone, watch and mac. After the restart of all devices I got the notification on the watch to trust the mac and I was able to start my application on the watch and iphone.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the best luck following these steps:

1. Quit Xcode
2. Disconnect iPhone
3. Turn bluetooth on watch off then on again
4. Reconnect iPhone, unlock and trust computer
5. Open Xcode

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I just needed to unplug and plug my iPhone in again.