# Paired device unavailable for development - after OSX Sierra and watchOS 3.1

Tags: xcode, watchkit, watchos-3

After upgrading my Macbook to OS X Sierra and my Apple Watch to watchOS 3.1, I've been getting the following error in the Xcode run project target item:

"Paired device unavailable for development"

It looks like people have encountered this in the past and this specific StackOverflow answer is linked when someone has this problem:
[iOS: Watch Kit paired device unavailable for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380684/ios-watch-kit-paired-device-unavailable-for-development/38044143#38044143)

However, I've done every single solution that has been listed and I'm still getting this issue. Is there any reason in particular why upgrading to Sierra and watchOS 3.1 would have caused this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the latest xcode beta (8.1 beta 3) appears to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. After I deleted `Xcode 9.1 beta` then open project with `Xcode 9.0`. I found that my `deployment target` is auto set to `iOS 11.1` which higher my `iPhone OS`. After change target to `iOS 9.0` it worked.[image]